# list attribute of object gets changed when calling del on a different attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, object, del

I am confused by the behaviour of the following code:

```
data = [0,1,2,3,4,5]

class test():
  def __init__(self,data):
   self.data=data
   self.data2=data

  def main(self):
    del self.data2[3]

test_var = test(data)
test_var.main()
print(test_var.data)
print(test_var.data2)
```

what i would think should come out is this:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5]
[0,1,2,4,5]
```

what i get is this:

```
[0,1,2,4,5]
[0,1,2,4,5]
```

Why is an element from the second list getting deleted when its not directly changed? Or does python handle attributes in such a way that this happens normally?

So how should i change the code that i get what i want?

Comment: You are assigning same `data` reference to different variables. The output is expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Lists` are mutable in Python and passed by reference. Whenever you assign it or pass it as an argument, a reference to it is passed and not a copy. Hence the outcome you're seeing. If you really want to mutate it, you need to deepcopy it.

```
import copy

class test():

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = copy.deepcopy(data)
        self.data2 = copy.deepcopy(data2)

# if the list is going to be flat and just contain basic immutable types,
# slicing (or shallow-copy) would do the job just as well.

class test():

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data[::] # or data[:] for that matter as @Joe Iddon suggested
        self.data2 = data[::]
```

> Note: not all types of objects support "deep-copying".

Comment: Nice answer, just to add, you can shallow copy with a single colon: `[:]`

Comment: thank you for this fast answer. i thought it would be some interaction i didnt get yet. welp one more mistake i wont be making in the future ^^

Comment: @JoeIddon Thanks. Yeah I know. Old habits die hard, I suppose.